# How to update an SQL column that has multiple values

Tags: sql, json

I have a column in my database that has multiple values, here is an example of what these values are:

The SQL column is called: `extra_fields` and is type `text`

```
[{"id":"2","value":"Ser mayor de edad"},
{"id":"3","value":"Prueba de extension"},
{"id":"4","value":"99.999.99"},
{"id":"5","value":"10"}}
```

I have this in a PHP function where I get the values I want to modify:

```
$db = $this->getDbo();
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM #__k2_items where id='.$item_id;
    $db->setQuery($query);

    $resultado = $db->loadObject();

$campos_extra = json_decode($resultado->extra_fields); 

    $num_max_cup_descargar = $campos_extra[2]->value;
    $num_max_cup_canjear = $campos_extra[3]->value;
    $num_max_cup_x_dia = $campos_extra[4]->value;
    $num_max_cup_uti_canje_x_user_dia = $campos_extra[5]->value;
    $num_max_cup_desc_user = $campos_extra[6]->value;
```

I am trying to update one of these values, how can I do this?

**EDIT:** Im using MySQL database.

Comment: If I understood this correctly - you're trying to write an array to the DB and update one entry from that array. Right? To which DB?

Comment: @ŁukaszRżanek exactly. When I decode the result I get from the database it returns in as objects inside an array. Now I want to update one of these values in my database. What do you mean which DB?

Comment: Which DB - MariaDB, MySQL, PostgreSQL?

Comment: @ŁukaszRżanek oh sorry, MySQL

Comment: @ŁukaszRżanek so?? so many questions for... ? :P

Comment: What is type of this column? If text/varchar, you're very likely to be required to update the entire string. And please drop that attitude for "so many questions" - first, author may be using different db than you and second - question is very unclear and hard to understand.

Comment: @keltar There was no attitude towards anybody, it was a non offensive comment but sorry anyways... The field is a `text` field and about the question being difficult to understand, I believe its pretty clear what im trying to do...

Comment: Do you know how to do an UPDATE against the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to Update the substring of some value in a text column with only SQL. MySQL doesn't care if you have a stringified JSON object in there or part of a Shakespeare play. You'll have to update this value by doing it in PHP:

> $campos_extra = json_decode($resultado->extra_fields);
>
> ```
> $num_max_cup_descargar = $campos_extra[2]->value;
> $num_max_cup_canjear = $campos_extra[3]->value;
> $num_max_cup_x_dia = $campos_extra[4]->value;
> $num_max_cup_uti_canje_x_user_dia = $campos_extra[5]->value;
> $num_max_cup_desc_user = $campos_extra[6]->value;
>
> $num_max_cup_desc_user = "changedUser";
> $campos_extra[6]->value = $num_max_cup_desc_user;
> ```
>
> $campos_extra_updated = json_encode($campos_extra);

And put $campos_extra_updated into that field of the database.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the value of `$campos_extra[6]->value` won't change here

Comment: I've revised my answer, sorry about the flaws before.

Answer (score 1):

In order to dynamically support such a queries you might use two different approaches:

1. Programmatically manipulate the data

   Well, this is rather simple - to summarize it nicely it means that you have to write the logic to manipulate the data end to end. The great benefit of that is a simple fact that your solution will not be dependent on the underlying DB engine.
2. Use the database specific extensions

   Most of the current RDBMS engines have some support for dynamic columns or array data stored in the tables. In case of MySQL there is an open source clone called MariaDB that have support for such a mechanism - see the documentation of [Dynamic Columns in MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/dynamic-columns/).

   With PostgreSQL you have an option to store [JSON and manipulate that directly (limited)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html), [array column](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/arrays.html), [composite types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rowtypes.html) if your properties are well defined or [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/hstore.html) to create a schema-less design.

   All of the above implementations will have their pros and cons, so you must pick wisely. But all of them comes with added benefits of indexing (and, therefore, queries) against to columns, some general SQL support, etc. Choose wisely :-)